# What should I know before trying to make a larger deadbolt hole?

Tags: doors, lock

I had a locksmith come over and check this out, but he ended up refusing the job. It seems pretty simple to me, but before I wanted to go give it a "try" I figure I would ask just so I have a better idea of options, what can go wrong, and maybe why an expert would refuse this job. I've already asked him about it and the answer was very vague and I don't want to bother him again.

I think I would need to drill a larger diameter hole for the new deadbolt, but the problem might be that the metallic strip doesn't leave enough room for a larger diameter hole.

Is my best solution to remove the metal strip drill the hole and repaint?

[image: current lock with 0.5 inches to metal strip]

Comment: So the “expert” refuses a job you say is simple... Why would he do that...

Comment: It is unclear what not enough room means. Not enough room for what?  Please add much more details so we can help you.

Comment: @SolarMike it _looks_ simple to me, but since he refused to do it I _know_ it probably isn't. I'm trying to get educated so I can figure out what my options are.

Comment: @Breedly  You have not told us WHAT he refused to do. What is the problem? Enlarging a dead bolt  tells us nothing.

Comment: Does “enlarge” mean lengthen?

Comment: What, specifically, do you want enlarged?

Comment: Thanks for the new info but it is still a little ambiguous. I think what you are asking is, you have new dead bolt lock that is to large for your the existing hole in the door. There are several questions with answers  on this stack exchange that address that problem. Locksmiths work on locks, not doors.  Search this site and you will find a couple of ways to accomplish creating a larger hole or filling the old one and drilling a new one.

Comment: YouTube is your friend. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4kjCnDX05g  -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgNAQedKUW0

Comment: Please tell us the size of the existing hole, the size hole you want to make, and the distance (on center) from the edge of the door to the middle of the existing hole. P.S. in lockset lingo, this last measurement is known as the *setback*.

Comment: This is simple your locksmith is an idiot! Probably learned the skill in prison and has no construction experience ... after several issues over the years guess what those that pick locks and are good are locksmiths after time served , maybe just my experience but I do have a few good friends now that were inside and they are the ones that have said this!!!  Get a contractor to adjust the hinges / jamb and even add steel plates with 4” screws into the framework, this still will not stop a size 15 boot with 250 lbs on a solid wood door, find someone that will fix both sides not a crook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know what the door is made out of and how to make the hole.

if the door will not be damaged by the larger hole, and you have the appropriate tools, go for it.

Maybe he refused because he didn't have the right tools to enlarge the existing hole in a tidy way